# Insert Blank Rows after Each Row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script and work fine. But I have one question: How to add rows with an text instead of white?

```
function addRows(){
  var startRow = 1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  for (var i=numRows; i > -1; i--) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + startRow, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Doesn't your current script add blank rows after each row already? What do you want to accomplish instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function addRows(){
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d=0;
  data.forEach(function(r,i){
    sheet.insertRowAfter(i+1+d++)
  });
}
```

Animation:

[image]